# detaching a sprite at a certain location in andengine

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I am developing a Game using AndEngine. In that I want to detach Sprites which have been dynamically attached into scene when an action occurs. How to tackle it?..Suppose you have X and Y coordinate of the sprite.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sprite.detachSelf() method to detach sprite from the scene.